# Normalisation of a SQL Database

Tags: sql, database-normalization

I do not feel this db is normalised since it has multiple information for the column address (address, county). What exactly is wrong, what level of normalisation does it fail?

[image]

Comment: This schema isn't even in first normal form. See your column street which consist from multiple values and also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: thats what i was thinking is it not atomic right? so if i put address and county separated instead of whats in street now it should be ok right?

Comment: It depends on your needs. For example, you can separate each part of address to own column (country, city, street, house, flat, etc). Or you can store full string of address into one column.

Comment: but then if i can store the full address in one column would it be in 1NF?

Comment: It depends on usage. If you doesn't want to select rows by street or by city or by house it would be ok, but otherwise it would be violation of 1NF

Comment: Do you need to be able to identify all addresses on Jersey Lane?  or all addresses with an address less than 100?  What about if it's an apt or if it has multiple units such as a business building?  how about if there are multiple phone numbers at one address?  There's lots of things here that COULD be changed.  What about a PO box vs a physical address?  Is this a 911 address vs a PO box?  what about Rual Route?  Most people simply store enough information for a mailing lablel Name, address 1 address 2 city, state zip.  What goes in address1 and address2 could be nearly anything.

Comment: yes, in this case i only use it as aggregated data and will never need to break it down for updates or anything. However, because it is for school, it has to be in BCNF. It is worth noting that in the registration page we ask the county in a separate input field so I think it would be better to separate that instead of aggregating it. The rest of the address in inputted by the user as aggregated.

Comment: In the US county isn't used on mailing labels.  Can't speak to other places.  But there's nothing stopping a user from entering county on address 1 or 2...  The only way to prevent this would be to do a lookup using the USPS address verification system; and adjust the address to one recognized.  So while I understand the desire for normal form.  You're basically hosed on street since a user could put in whatever they want...   again an address could have multiple phone lines so I might want to break that guy out for normal form.

Comment: If it's a school question they probably want you to identify that the _,county_ part needs to be in a different field. Perhaps also that you could split zip, city, country into different tables. Normally these things are driven by 'business' process which means you ask the user of the system whether they care about zip, country, city enough to do this. But being a school project, it's whatever your teacher thinks is right.